# how to get serialized part out of this response and other array keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, string

i am receving a response from a third party service in the following way.

```
  Array
(
    [created_on] => 2012-09-13 01:47:05
    [recipe] => SAMSave
    [requesters_id] => 1
    [status] => New
    [args] => a:5:{s:4:"name";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Frank";s:9:"last_name";s:7:"McCourt";s:11:"middle_name";s:4:"FAKE";s:5:"email";s:0:"";}}s:3:"dob";a:3:{s:5:"month";s:4:"1955";s:4:"year";s:2:"05";s:3:"day";s:2:"15";}s:3:"ssn";s:9:"411449097";s:7:"address";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:6:"street";s:23:"1243 PUBLIC WORKS DRIVE";s:4:"city";s:11:"Chattanooga";s:5:"state";s:2:"TN";s:3:"zip";s:5:"37403";}}s:5:"phone";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:6:"number";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:1:"P";}}}
)
true{"status":"Success","message":"Request Added!","id":416}
```

The whole thing starting from Array till the end is in string format. I have to get the data out from this string , Every time i think i end up with the solution of regular expression to get the data out . I wish i knew a function which can construct that into a PHP Array with the same keys and values. If any one has better solution other then using regular expression please share your thoughts / comments.

I have used unserialize on this string and get error : `Error at offset 0 of 654 bytes`

The Orinial Response i receive is in a single line , the above out put i grabbed from 
the browser after printing it with `'<pre>'` 
.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if it's just serialized php data, then try this:

```
$data = unserialized($string_from_third_party);
```

Comment: I think he's saying that he gets that whole code block back. This would only take care of the 'args' bit. It looks like someone just print_r'd their data... :P

Comment: thanks @chovy:  i get error when i unserialize it. i think the last part true{"status":"Success","message":"Request Added!","id":416} may be making the whole serialize corrupt

Comment: could be, it looks like serialized data though.

Comment: strip that part out, but really it looks look a crappy api, maybe they should fix it and give you something usable.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the EXACT response you receive, it looks like someone is just print_r'ing their data, and maybe even a few times with that 'true' bit at the end too.

What the response looks like is you've sent the data that's in 'args' and their giving you a response back saying it was successfully stored.

With that as my thoughts for this answer, I came to the conclusion you already have the data in 'args', the rest of it isn't really all that important, so, back to me saying if that's the EXACT response you get, then just grab the last line of the response, strip the 'true' off the beginning, maybe also strip 'false' from the beginning for a unsuccessful save, then using the remaining string left on that line, you can json_decode that and you'll get what you're after.

So as an example:

```
// GIVEN: $string_from_server is set to the response
$string_from_server_split_into_lines = str_split($string_from_server, '\n');
$last_line_from_server = array_pop($string_from_server_split_into_lines);
$json_object = json_decode(str_replace('true', '', str_replace('false', '', $last_line_from_server)));
var_dump($json_object);
```

I know it's messy but hey that sounds like you're best shot. :)

Comment: Thanks @FlukkyJack:  There are no lines i print out the response using <pre>.print_r($response,true), i want to use the all the data and store it into db tables as well

Comment: OH! I was wondering why someone would return data as a response formatted with print_r haha. Well that means the response you're getting is just an associative array... I think I don't know if I'm understanding clearly. Just try `print_r(unserialize($response['args']));` and see what you get.

Comment: Just try `print_r($response['args'])` and see what you get then.